# I have a hard time sending Map data from ajax to spring controller

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am implementing a way to send a map to Spring Controller via ajax.

However, when I receive the map data from the controller, I receive the map data that contains nothing.

Map.size = 0...

Help me.

```
deduction: function (tr) {
    var tr = $('tr[name=resultTable]');
    var data = new Map();

    for (var index = 0, size = tr.length; index < size; ++index) {
        var td = tr.eq(index).children();

        if (td.eq(1) === "COLOR") continue;

        data.set(td.eq(5).text(), td.eq(3).text());
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/api/v1/stock/deduction',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function () {
        alert('ok');
        window.location.reload();
    }).fail(function () {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}

@PutMapping("/api/v1/stock/deduction")
public Long stockDeduction (@RequestBody Map<String, String> deductionMap) {
    System.out.println(deductionMap.size());

    return 1L;
}
```

We have confirmed that the map data to be transmitted has been correctly entered.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243462/ajax-pass-a-map-object-to-spring-mvc-controller

Comment: thanks.. but i no have server side error message.. TT

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem...

I used the map in the same way as "myMap.set (key, value)".

This is a problem

I had to write mymap [key] = [value] so the map was delivered correctly.